# How does a virtual inheritance triangle work where both vertices inherit the third virtually but regularly between themselves?

Tags: c++, virtual

I have the following code and I am a bit confused with the output:

```
class A{
    protected:
        int x;
    public:
        A() { x = 1; }
        void print() { cout << "X: " << x << endl; }
};

class B: virtual public A{
    protected:
        int x;
    public:
        B() { x = 2; }
};

class C: virtual public A, public B {
    public:
        C() { x = 3; }
};

int main() { 
    C c;
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:
X 1

Can someone please explain the process of how this happened?
why does C() ctor x = 3 change B::x and not A::x?
Does it have only one parent class A? even though it inherits B class regularly

Comment: when C does x=3, why doesnt it change A's x?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and it will mention that `B::x` shadows `A::x`.

Comment: for the gory details see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Comment: I understand that B::x shadows A::x, I don't understand how C knew to head to parent class B, and not parent class A, since he derives both directly.

Comment: Because B::x shadows A::x.

Comment: yes, but I guess I'm unaware of how that changes things, hence "please explain the process"

Comment: It's not a simple process, it's described in full [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.member.lookup). I have yet to see it explained more simply than the formal version.

Comment: Its in the link above, search for "Either way, when examining the bases ..." Usually cppreferene does a great job at explaining things for mortals, but this is just too weird :D.  I don't completely understand the rules prior to c++11, but since c++11 i am just lost. I think the examples are better at explaining it than the text

Comment: Don't write code like this!  Then the problem will go away all by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. The key term here is **dominance**. Take a simpler example:

```
struct B: virtual A {
    int x;
};

struct C : B {
    C() { x = 3; }
};
```

Here, clearly, the assignment `x = 3;` assigns to the `x` in `B`, because name lookup stops when the compiler sees the `x` in `B` and it doesn't look in `A` for another `x`.

In the example in the question there's also a direct inheritance from `A`:

```
struct C : B, virtual A {
    C() { x = 3; }
};
```

Now there are still two distinct `x` objects: one in `B` and one in `A`, and at first glance, the mention of `x` in `C::C()` looks ambiguous: is it the one that comes from `C`'s base `B` or the one that comes from `C`'s base `A`?

The dominance rule says that `B`'s version of `x` hides `A`'s version, even though `A` is a direct base of `C`. Basically, the rule is that since `A::x` is hidden along one branch of the inheritance chain, it's hidden along all branches. Formally,

> When virtual base classes are used, a hidden declaration can be
> reached along a path through the subobject lattice that does not pass
> through the hiding declaration. This is not an ambiguity.

This only applies among `A`s that are virtual bases:

```
struct C : B, A {
    C() { x = 3; }
};
```

Here, `x` is ambiguous; it could mean `B::x` or it could mean `A::x` (but not the `A::x` in the virtual base of `B`).

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `C` is assigning the `B`'s member variable `x` not the `A`'s one, the `print` method is from the `A` class, that is accessing the `A`'s `x` member variable value, which is `1`.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: how does it get over the ambiguity of choosing B x over A x since he inherits both?

Comment: I believe this is because inheritance from `A` is always virtual, then `B`'s `x` member variable shadows it. Inheritance from `A` has two paths, one through `B` and one direct. When `x` is dereferenced, it stops at the first non-virtual member, which is `B`'s `x`, Sadly, I couldn't find any formal doc about it to add as a reference.

Comment: Well, answer from @pete, explains it very clearly :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806126/3444205